# Using top command i wrote one script and output also stored in doc file with date in single line

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am monitoring my cloud server so I wrote a script using `top` command and stored the output  file in single line  with date , but its not working

```
(date)&&(top -n 1 | grep firefox) >> filename.txt
```

Kindly help me

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

The following command should work:

```
((date | tr -d "\n")&&(top -b -n 1 | grep firefox)) >> filename.txt
```

2 fixes:

1. I enclosed in parentheses the full command so that even the `date` output is redirected to the file, the `tr` part just removing the carriage return.
2. I use `top` in batch mode `-b` to get the full list of processes.

Comment: hi sylvain what is the purpose for tr -d

Comment: @jobfinatel `tr -d` means delete this character. here the carriage return.  That way both the date and the result from the top command are on a single line

Answer (score 0):

i think firefox will not always appear on the top output, so what about

```
((date) && (ps aux | grep firefox | grep -v grep)) >> filename.txt
```

It's the same info, in a different format, and you could always be sure that you will get firefox info if it's running.

Comment: and i get a output for this terminal                                                                        #!/bin/bash
echo $(date) / $(top -b -n 1 | grep firefox)>>

Comment: Now i run this script in my shell script now is working but i need some clarification how to i import the excell sheet